# Authentication with the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I'm having trouble getting data from a SoundCloud user in a Chrome Extension I'm building. I'm calling the init function like this:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: '####',
    redirect_uri: "chrome-extension://####/callback.html"
});
```

And then calling the connect function like this:

```
SC.connect(function() {
    SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
        alert('Hello, ' + me.username); 
    });
});
```

This opens up a login popup which upon submit redirects to callback.html that tries to do the following:

```
window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1);
```

The problem is that window.opener is null and thus connectCallback never gets executed. Is there any way to make the authentication flow work with a Chrome Extension?

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication